# How to use MySQL SET Variables in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

How do I use the MySQL Variables that I used in DB::statement(). I put the two variables there which are @num and @type.

I have a query builder after the DB::statement() which will used the @num and @type variables.

Upon running, both variables return NULL since it cannot get the MySQL variables.

| id | number | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 2 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 3 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 4 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 5 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 6 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 7 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 8 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 9 | (NULL) | (NULL) |
| 10 | (NULL) | (NULL) |

**Expected output should be:**

| id | number | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |

**Here's the actual code:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Laravel has a concept of a read connection vs. a write connection. I suspect your `SET` statement is running against the write connection, and the subsequent `SELECT` query is running against the read connection. But your user-defined variables are only set in the connection where you `SET` them. You need to find a way with the Laravel API to run both queries against the same connection. I'm not practiced in Laravel, but I see one way to do this is to wrap the statements in a DB::transaction() callback. There may be other ways.

Comment: Ok, thanks @BillKarwin. I've solve the problem. I'm glad that I found a similar problem and you are right, I need to put the initialization of the mysql variable to the same query. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the same query. It just has to be on the same connection. You can execute more than one SQL statement on a connection. The user-defined variables are local to that connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this. I found out that there is an inline in from().

[image]

**Reference:**

https://laravel.io/forum/12-18-2014-how-to-initialize-user-defined-mysql-variables?fbclid=IwAR1hsMZ-J4iDAza3qiZaQcOIY1OMVzLh_wFM0JBvUb50xX4mcENrxJnVM_M#18872

Comment: What I do not understand is why you'd use Laravel rather than just using mySQL queries?   It appears to me Laravel adds an unnecessary level of complexity.   I know noting about Laravel , I just see so many Laravel questions here only because Laravel added this unnecessary level complexity.  What is the benefit that Laravel gives you?  I'm old school.  Why fix it (with Laravel) if it's not broken?

Comment: In the vast majority of cases the query builder removes a level of complexity from SQL queries, in this particular use case a raw SQL query probably makes more sense though.